# angularjs ng-model not able to access in controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I can't able to access this ng-model name **`viewProfileCtrl.monthsForm.institution`** in Controller

```
<select class="perf-select" ng-model="viewProfileCtrl.monthsForm.institution"
                           ng-options="inst.institution.institution_id as inst.institution.name for inst in viewProfileCtrl.perfiosAnalysisData.institutions"
                           ng-change="viewProfileCtrl.setCurrMonthInsti(viewProfileCtrl.monthsForm.institution)">
                           <option value=""  selected>Select a Bank</option>
                        </select>
```

if i try to access it show error like this
**`TypeError: Cannot set property 'institution' of undefined`**

How i can access this ?

**myjs**

```
vm.monthsForm.institution = vm.perfiosAnalysisData.institutions[0].institution.institution_id;
```

Comment: it seems, you don't have viewProfileCtrl.monthsForm. can you please post js code?

Comment: Please check now ii added this way

Comment: where are you defining `monthsForm` in vm?

Comment: I used only this code

Comment: you should define `monthsFrom` before assigning `institution` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your js, you should define monthsFrom before assigning `institution` property in it.

You can do like this :

```
vm.monthsForm = {
        'institution' : vm.perfiosAnalysisData.institutions[0].institution.institution_id;
};
```